# Broadcast message for identified user with ActionCable from non Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I have action cable channel with identified user

```rb
class DesktopNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed
    reject and return unless current_user.present?
    logger.add_tags 'ActionCable DesktopNotificationsChannel', current_user.id
    stream_for current_user
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

And i'm connecting this channel from my external application (Desktop application written in C# and I'm using WebSocketSharp library for connections). I can successfully listen all broadcasted messages that sent with,

```rb
  DesktopNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(user, data: 'Some Data' )
```

But i also want to broadcast message from external application. I've tried various ways to broadcast message for specific user but actioncable ignores the message I'm trying to send;

```json
{
    "command": "message",
    "data": {"status": "current_status"},
    "identifier": { "channel": "DesktopNotificationsChannel"}
}
```

I figured out i have to add user_id or global_id for user that i want to send message in that json but i couldn't succeed.

I also tried change identifier with rails' broadcaster key like `desktop_notifications:xxyyyzz` but it also didn't work.

I'm missing something but couldn't figured. How can i send broadcast message for specific user from my non rails application.

Comment: What endpoint are you sending the message to?

Comment: My action_cable.mount_path refers "/cable" and i'm receiving and trying to send that endpoint.

Comment: Where is the web app running? Local? Is the app you are using in its allowed request origins?

Comment: Also I notice in some discussions that "all contents must be a string", so in JS they will use something like `socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));` Does the C# library handle that for you?

Comment: Yes i also tried to create escaped json manually to see if there is encoding error. but it didn't have problem. also i can successfully send subscribe message with with same format with success. My both applications running in local and im running my puma with ```-b 0.0.0.0``` parameter and my dotnet application connects with local ip. Request origins allowed at least in my development env i disabled with ```config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fetch messages by adding `stream_from` and `receive` method to my channel. I don't know its proper way to do but it but it's working like this.

```rb
class DesktopNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed
    reject and return unless current_user.present?
    logger.add_tags 'ActionCable DesktopNotificationsChannel', current_user.id
    stream_for current_user
    stream_from current_user
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def receive(data)
    DesktopNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(current_user, data:)
  end
end
```